# Google Cloud Messaging Waiting For Register

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

In my GCM project, I want to wait for AsyncTask until the register returns.

I've tried to use `synchronized` and `CountDownLatch` to wait in the main thread.

However, every time I wait, my app exits with exception SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE on register method.

Why does this exception occur? I get a perfectly fine registration ID normally. Also, the waiting process is successful without the register method.

Thx for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error comes often with the GCM register() method. You can try the following:

1. Add REGISTRATION to the GcmBroadcastReceiver Intent Filter in AndroidManifest.xml file

   `<receiver
    android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
         <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
         <category android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
   </receiver>`
2. Obtain the Registration ID in GcmBroadcastReceivers `onReceive` method

   `@Override`

   `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {`

   ```
   String regId = intent.getExtras().getString("registration_id");
   ```

   `}`

Hope this works for you.